# Is there a way to conditionally configure a source input plugin in fluentd?

Tags: fluentd

I have a generic fluentd conf that I am using for multiple services.

> fluent.conf

```
<source>
  @type dummy
  dummy {"hello":"world"}
</source>
<match>
  @type stdout
</match>
```

In this config I want to inject the S3 source input plugin (below snippet) based on a condition. The condition could be if a specific env variable is set to true inject this source otherwise skip. Is there a way to to do this

```
<source>
  @type s3
  tag input.s3
  s3_bucket "#{ENV['S3_BUCKET']}"
  s3_region "#{ENV['S3_REGION']}"
  add_object_metadata true
  store_as gzip
  <sqs>
    queue_name "#{ENV['SQS_QUEUE']}"
  </sqs>
</source>
```

Or if there are other ways to handle this please let me know.

Comment: What kind of config do you want to inject? Please add an example.

Comment: The source s3 input plugin is what I need to inject to the fluentd config

Comment: Isn't that config working already? What exactly do you mean by injecting? Inject values via environment variables or something else?

Comment: @Azeem I have edited the question. I hope it is more clear now.

Comment: In that `dummy` config, `tag` is missing and the `match` also doesn't have the `tag` configured. But, I get your point that you already have some config and you want to switch it or enhance it by injecting it with the S3 config, right? Why can you not have both in there? You could have multiple `source` sections.

Comment: Yes, you got the requirement right. The reason I cannot have the s3 source is because there are environments where i do not want to source from s3 plugin and the s3 bucket does not exist

Comment: Right. What is your deployment like? Are you using Docker with Kubernetes (with Helm charts)?

Comment: You can write a shell script to preprocess the config file based on env vars to inject your required config if you're using it directly.

Comment: I am using Docker with ECS. Would you be able to share an example to do this?

Comment: Right. No, I haven't used ECS. I believe you'll find out ways to do this over there e.g. create two different config files and switch between them via some env var inside the entry point script or something like that.